# Access 2010 Trying to Enter a unique record through Form

Tags: forms, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I'm trying to input an error check for my form. I have the user entering the name and I would like a prompt to inform them if they are attempting to use a Name already in the records.

Example: the Person table has 3 records with FNames being:  Jeff, Kyle, Darren.

If on the add person form in the Fname Box Kyle is entered, the after update event will notify the user that this name has been claimed and null the field. Where as if Greg was enter no notifications will occur.

I just don't know how to compare a text field value to values in a filtered query list, and Google searches have other loosely related links in the way.

Thank you for help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all fnames must be unique, add a unique index to the table. This will prevent duplicates being entered. The form error property will allow you to provide a custom error.

You can also check if the name exists in the Before Update event of the control.

In this example, the control and field are both called AText. Generally, you should rename controls so they are not the same as fields.

```
Private Sub AText_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)
Dim IsOk As Boolean

''One of the very few places where the .Text property is used
sLookUp = Me.AText.Text

IsOk = IsNull(DLookup("Atext", "Table1", "Atext='" & sLookUp & "'"))

If Not IsOk Then
    MsgBox "Found!"
    Cancel = True
End If
End Sub
```